# Python program summation of a series

Tags: python, series, factorial, exponential

I tried to create a program in python which basically sums up a series up to the term which is less than 0 that goes like: 
`1+((2X)/1!)+((3X^2)/2!)+((4X^3)/3!)....`
I designed a basic term every term in the series that is `((A+1)((X)^A))/A!` where `A` is incremented in a loop through the terms. The program below gives no compilation error however it is not showing the result. Please help. It would be really appreciated. Thank you!

```
import decimal
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*(fact(n-1))
x = int(input("Enter the value of x"))
A=0
summation=0
sumt1=(A+1)
sumt2=(x**A)
sumt3=fact(x)
sumt4=sumt1*sumt2
sumt5=sumt4/sumt3

while (sumt5 > 0.00) :
    summation = summation+sumt5
    A+=1
finalsum=decimal.Decimal(1+summation)
print("The value is")
print(finalsum)
```

Comment: You never modify the value of `sumt5`, so `(sumt5 > 0.00)` will always be true and the loop will never end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `sumt` variables into your while loop, and then break out of the loop when `sumt5 <= 0.00`:

```
import decimal

def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*(fact(n-1))

x = 1  # Hardcoded for this example, instead of prompting.
A = 0
summation = 1.0

while True:
    sumt1 = A + 1
    sumt2 = x**A
    sumt3 = fact(A)  # Was `fact(x)` in original code, which didn't match your formula & prevented `sumt5 <= 0.00` from ever being true.
    sumt4 = sumt1 * sumt2
    sumt5 = sumt4/sumt3

    summation += sumt5
    A += 1

    if sumt5 <= 0.00:
        break


finalsum=decimal.Decimal(summation)
print("The value is {}.".format(finalsum))
```

## Updated Answer

I wanted to understand what was happening better for myself, so I broke the summation out into a separate function and, rather than calculating all the individual terms separately, I plugged them directly into the function you gave in the OP: `((A+1)((X)^A))/A!`.  Here's my code:

```
import decimal

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)


def summation(num):
    A = 0
    result = 1.0

    while True:
        term = (A + 1) * num**A / factorial(A)
        result += term
        A += 1

        if term <= 0.0:  # Break out of the loop when the `term <= 0`.
            break

    return result


# Sample output.    
for i in range(1, 11):
    final = decimal.Decimal(summation(i))
    print('summation({}) == {}'.format(i, final))
```

When I ran it, I received the following output:

```
final == 6.43656365691809018159119659685529768466949462890625
final == 23.167168296791945891754949116148054599761962890625
final == 81.3421476927506574838844244368374347686767578125
final == 273.99075016572106733292457647621631622314453125
final == 891.478954615459542765165679156780242919921875
final == 2825.00155444914480540319345891475677490234375
final == 8774.06526742766800452955067157745361328125
final == 26829.62188337555198813788592815399169921875
final == 81031.839275753838592208921909332275390625
final == 242292.12374287386774085462093353271484375
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally working now. Brilliant job debugging the code, I was getting headaches from it.

Comment: Follow up question and this might be an easy one. How do I modify the code so the for loop sums the terms upto before the term which is less than or equal to zero. You have a specific range in your code which is 1,11 but what if the term is for example the 56th term in one run and 101th in another. Can I use a variable in the range()? If so where should I define that variable. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean modify the `while` loop?  In this case, the `for` loop is just being used for demonstration purposes.  If you're referring to the `while` loop, just move the `if ... break` so that it's ahead of `result += term`.  That way it will still calculate the term, but only add it to the result if `term > 0.0`.  And yes - you can use a variable in the `range()` (again, that's only there for demonstration purposes, though, it's not an essential part of the solution).  You can define that variable however you want - i.e., an `input()` statement, like you used in your original post.

Comment: Once again thanks so much for the help. I'm a beginner at programming and trying to learn on my own. Support from people like you means a lot and goes a long way in enriching the programming community.